# Fuzzy launcher after wakeup from suspend

Tags: launcher, visual-artifacts

I am new to Ubuntu, using the Nvidia 'version 310' proprietary graphics driver. Every time I wake the system from suspend, I get a fuzzy launcher with geometric artifacts. After hovering the mouse over it, everything goes fine and remains fine too. This is how my desktop looks after resuming from Suspend:

[image: This is how it looks like after Suspend]

Answer (score 0):

My opinion it seems that your graphic driver is not matched with your nvidia card. So lets use another driver. Did you check on additional driver to see if your current driver is recommended mode or other ones?

I had similar problem with my nvidia driver. First I checked into my system bios setup and unchecked optimus technology for nvidia then reinstalled my nvidia driver and it goes well for me.

Comment: i followed as you said.i am currently using the "tested" Nvidia driver.and there is no "optimus technology for nvidia" in my BIOS settings.any ideas?